# How to restore WordPress theme style,css from caches on internet

Tags: css, restore

I deleted mistakly my child theme in wordpress site.

Is there any way I can get CSS contant somewhere cached over internet?

Comment: Try this: https://web.archive.org/web/

Comment: Tried, has only from 2014.

Comment: Try to search in google `cache:yoursite.com`.

Comment: Or try this: http://cachedview.com/

Comment: my first thought was googles cache. I havn't tried it before so I don't know if it backs up everything. some more details might help.

Comment: Well, we need to know the browser you were using ?

Comment: Was using chrome, but seems chrome does not cache css. Activated new theme, I need some site that have cached theme/style.css back these days. Chrome didn't work, or any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using Chrome, and had open the style.css file at least once then you may use this method  to recover the cache:

```
chrome://cache/
```

You will get all the list of cached data there. Then ctrl+f to find the style.css for the same.

Once you find it. Copy all the data => Go [Here](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2012/01/viewing-chrome-cache-easy-way.html) and paste it in the text box.

See if it works.!

or you can try to open `cache:domain.com` as well.

Comment: Have you converted the cache file? When do you get Unrecognized format?

Comment: When I paste contents of chrome://cache/ to http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2012/01/viewing-chrome-cache-easy-way.html

Comment: And it goes to chrome://view-http-cache/ instead chrome://cache/

Comment: U need to select the specific file which you want to recover. Are you copying just all the content from chrome://cache/  or chrome://view-http-cache/ and trying to paste there?

Comment: /* CSS wayback retrieval error:

 Title:   Hrm.
 Message: Wayback Machine doesn&apos;t have that page archived.
 
 */

Comment: Retreived css from cached wordpress theme editor. Your answer works, just used a logic.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally wiped a CSS file, the website was still cashed so I inspected one of the elements and viewed the cached css resource and copied it from there.